# How do you get the Nitwit easier on Macbook?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really want one in my village but no matter how many I spawn it's just a normal villager.

Can you help me?

Comment: Nitwits are unemployed villagers that can't be employed. Are you even sure you want one?

Comment: @Dabbingsdednow that's precisely why you would want one

Comment: Are you on an older version?

Answer (score 0):

Using commands:

```
summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData:{level:1,profession:"minecraft:nitwit"}}
```

Then add "type:" to change the villagers apperance:

```
summon minecraft:villager ~ ~ ~ {VillagerData:{level:1,profession:"minecraft:nitwit",type:"minecraft:desert"}}
```